# Parse Server working for JavaScript SDK but not working for Android

Tags: android, node.js, parse-platform, connection, parse-server

I am trying to create local parse server (node.js) and connect it to android and javascript sdk
but when I put the app id & server url & client key in Android , and trying to query an object , the application throwing **ParseException no_connection**

the keys and url I write :

```
<string name="parse_server_url" translatable="false">http://192.168.1.200:1337/parse/</string>
<string name="parse_app_id" translatable="false">myapp</string>
<string name="parse_client_key" translatable="false">myclientkey</string>
```

**(This strings for AndroidManifest.xml metadata + Parse.initialize() in the App java file)**

javascript sdk working normally
even the dashboard opening normally...

when I try to write the server url in android device browser , the page opening normally...
I tried to use different parse-server versions *(2.1.x/4.5.0/6.2.1)*
but the only sdk working is **JavaScript** SDK.

***Edit :*** This is Parse Initialize App.java :

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
            .applicationId(getString(R.string.parse_app_id))
            .clientKey(getString(R.string.parse_client_key))
            .server(getString(R.string.parse_server_url))
            .enableLocalDataStore()
            .build());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to application tag in AndroidManiFest.xml